# How to send the APDU command to get a success response?

Tags: javacard, apdu

I have this method in my javacard applet:

```
 public void process(APDU apdu)  
{
  byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer() ;  
  switch(buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS])  
   { 
   case 0x40: 
              Util.arrayCopy(hello,(byte)0,buf,ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA,(byte)5); 
              apdu.setOutgoingAndSend(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA,(byte)5); 
              break; 

   default:  ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_INS) ;  
   }
}
```

Here hello is :

```
 private final static byte[] hello =  {0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f };
```

and  I am sending the command in the script as follows:

```
 powerup;

// Select the installer applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09 0xa0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0x08 0x01 0x7F;

// create TestApplet applet
0x80 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0xd 0xb 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

//show hello message
0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00;  //this is the command mentioned in tutorial which gave error

powerdown;
```

The first two commands are succeeded, but the last one gets the error as the command is not in correct format .

I also tried this command:

```
     0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7f;
```

But it gave me the response `6d00` which means `INS` vlaue not supported.

Here is the actual Response:

```
CLA: 80, INS:40, P1:00,P2:00,Lc:00,Le:00,SW1:6d,SW2:00
```

The expected response is to get the hello value along with the success reponse `9000`

I am following the [tutorial](http://javacard.vetilles.com/2006/09/17/hello-world-smart-card/)

What is the proper way to give the APDU command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by @BzH, command `0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00` is not correct.

The correct command is

`0x80 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00`.

There is one more problem: status word `6D00` is not sent by your applet, it is sent by the card manager applet with

```
AID = A00000006203010801
```

you have selected after `powerup`. The card manager applet does not know `INS = 0x40` instruction, therefore the status code. You have to select your applet before sending any commands:

```
00 A4 04 00 [Lc] [... AID of your applet instance...]
80 40 00 00 00
```

Comment: when I tried this, it gave me the  parse Exception encountered ";" at line 11 error, was expecting one of integer_literal, character_literal,string_literal...

Answer (score 2):

The card's Global Platform class byte is `0x80`. So you should send:

```
 0x80 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

The first APDU you are sending `0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00` is wrong, because `0x40` is considered as the class byte and `0x00` as Instruction.

Comment: when I tried this, it gave me the  parse Exception encountered ";" at line 11 error, was expecting one of integer_literal, character_literal,string_literal...

Answer (score 0):

Finally this command worked for me.

As the APDU commands should be given in a format,

There are four cases to be followed , when sending commands to APDU:

```
Case    Command data    Expected response data
1        No data            No data
2        No data            Data
3        Data              No data
4        Data               Data
```

- In case 1, the length Lc is null; therefore the Lc field and the data field are empty. The length Le is also null; therefore the Le field is empty. Consequently, the body is empty.
- In case 2, the length Lc is null; therefore the Lc field and the data field are empty. The length of Le is not null; therefore the Le field is present. Consequently, the body consists of the Le field.
- In case 3, the length Lc is not null; therefore the Lc field is present and the data field consists of the Lc subsequent bytes. The length Le is null; therefore the Le field is empty. Consequently, the body consists of the Lc field followed by the data field.
- In case 4, the length Lc is not null; therefore the Lc field is present and the data field consists of the Lc subsequent bytes. The length Le is also not null; therefore the Le field is also present. Consequently, the body consists of the Lc field followed by the data field and the Le field.

So in my case it will be case 4 , I need to send some bytes, and get some bytes.

So the command in this case should be:

```
  0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x05 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x05;
   CLA INS    P1   P2  Lc   b1   b2   b3   b4   b5   Le

      Lc- input byte length (0x05 followed by 5 bytes of input: 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00)
      Le- expeted output byte length (H,e,l,l,o in my case it is 5 bytes. Hence 0x05)
```

and I got the repsonse as:

```
 CLA:00 INS:40 P1:00 P2:00 Lc:05,00,40,00,00,00 Le:05,48,65,6c,6c,6f SW1:90 SW2:00
```

I got the Word H,e,l,l,o in the Le field.

As suggested by @Vojta ,And another mistake I did is, I am running the command without selecting the applet,

So, the correct order should be

```
 power up

 //create installer applet

 //create testapplet

 //select test appplet   (I missed this step in my question)

 //run get Hello Command

 powerdown;
```

Comment: This might have worked, but it is definitely wrong. Your command is not a case 4 APDU, but a case 2 APDU. You don't want to send any input data. You just need to read output data. Each APDU consists of a header and a data part. The header is always present, the data part is optional. Lc byte contains length of the data part, not the whole APDU. I really don't know why you send the header also in the data part - it does not make sense. Your response notation is also confusing: it looks like response contains the whole command, but it does not.

Comment: But when I just give the 00 40 00 00 00, I get the error: when I tried this, it gave me the parse Exception encountered ";" at line 11 error, was expecting one of integer_literal, character_literal,string_literal.. @vojta

Comment: As Dear Vojta and dear BzH mentioned in their answers and comments, you should: **1- Select your applet** and **2- Send `80 40 00 00 00`** to your card to receive hello in response. As you are using JCDK simulator and it is based on an old Smart Card Reader that used `0x7f` at the end of apdu commands as separator, you must add this byte at the end of both SELECT command and SHOW HELLO command. So you must send `00 a4 04 00 09 a0 00 00 00 62 03 01 08 01 7f` and then `80 40 00 00 00 7f` to receive `Hello` recponse. Any other sequence is wrong (even with expected response)

Comment: As you didn't restrict CLA bytes in your applet, `00 40 00 00 00 7f` will work for rhe second command too.

Comment: Excellent, If you could add that as an answer. I will upvote it. All that valuable info should be as an answer.

Comment: I have never heard of using 0x7F as APDU separator, thanks for posting that, @Abraham !

Comment: @vojta, you're welcome dear Vojta.I double checked source. Actually I was a little wrong in previous comment. The simulator in JCDK is based on TLP224 protocol(an old reader). In this protocol we use 0x7F as Le, in cases that Le is zero. Here is the [source](https://www.techylib.com/en/view/cabbagepatchtexas/java_card_3_programming_michel_koenig_installing_and).